# react chart js skip zero value month

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

i have a line chart showing donations per month. however i have records showing with months without donations. my json data looks like this.

```
"content": [
    {
        "donation_amount": "10",
        "avg_donation_amount": 10.0,
        "transaction_count": 1,
        "month": 2
    },
    {
        "donation_amount": "60",
        "avg_donation_amount": 60.0,
        "transaction_count": 1,
        "month": 3
    },
    {
        "donation_amount": "1556",
        "avg_donation_amount": 97.00,
        "transaction_count": 3,
        "month": 4
    }
]
```

which month represents for ex: 2 is february, 3 is march, 4 is april. now i still need to show that there is no donation came from the month of january.

this is my js file

```
async countDonationsPerMonth(){
let URL = BASE_URL+"donors_by_month";
let x = [];
let y = [];
let item = [];
try {
    const response = await fetch(URL,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bareer ' + this.getUserAuth()
        }
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    let content = data.content;
    content.map((item, key) =>
      y.push(item.donation_amount)
    );
    this.setState({
        donation_amount: y
    })
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
}

render() {
const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    datasets: [
        {
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.4)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            data: this.state.donation_amount
        }
    ]
};

return (
  <div>
    <Card title="Campaign Donations">
    <Line
      data={data}
      width={150}
      height={40}
    />
    </Card>
  </div>
);
```

}

expected output for data[0,10,60,1556,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

i still wants to push to array with zero donation_amount.
any help would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: hi see my answer do you want them to be strings or integers?

Comment: integer my friend

Comment: updated the code , see snippet

Comment: woah! great. this solved my problem. thanks @Rkv88-Kanyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
y=Array.from(Array(12)).fill(0);
content.map((item,i) =>{y[parseInt(item.month)-1]=parseInt(item.donation_amount)});
```

.

output example
.

```js
content = [{
    "donation_amount": "10",
    "avg_donation_amount": 10.0,
    "transaction_count": 1,
    "month": 2
  },
  {
    "donation_amount": "60",
    "avg_donation_amount": 60.0,
    "transaction_count": 1,
    "month": 3
  },
  {
    "donation_amount": "1556",
    "avg_donation_amount": 97.00,
    "transaction_count": 3,
    "month": 4
  }
];

y = Array.from(Array(12)).fill(0);
content.map((item, i) => {
  y[parseInt(item.month) - 1] = parseInt(item.donation_amount)
});
console.log(y);
```